# Scrollview not working

Tags: android

This is my coding i have added a toolbar and i want the data below to scroll but its scrolling entirely.I Tried many solution in SO but still its of No use.Pls check and if found any error help me

Thanks in Advance

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.agna.hrm_sainmarks.Address" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/emergencytoolbar"
            layout="@layout/emergency_toolbar" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/name"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Ajith Kumar"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/relationship"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primrelationship"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Brother"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/phone"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primphone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="9998885231"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/taddress"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primaddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="78,Muthu nagar 3rd Street,Coimbatore-44"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

emergency_toolbar

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <!-- <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/Hrmtool"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/Red" > -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:weightSum="2"
                 >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/pemergency"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="@color/Hrmbg"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:textSize="18dp" 
                    android:text="@string/pemergency"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/semergency"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="@color/Hrmbg"

                     android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:textSize="18dp" 
                    android:text="@string/semergency"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black" />
            </LinearLayout>
       <!--  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> -->


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `ScrollView` can have only one direct child.

Comment: yea i know that but when i added linear layout below scroll view the app is getting  crash

Comment: Then post that code with logcat error.

Comment: i cant able to post my log cat here

Comment: @PreethiRajan show us your logcat . and check my answer also. if you have tried same and getting crash then post `Logcat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do just few changes.

1. In `emergency_toolbar.xml` change the `layout_height` of `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`.
2. In `activity_main.xml` put `<include....` code outside `LinearLayout` and Inside of `RelativeLayout`.
3. You have to add `LinearLayout` just after `ScrollView` to wrap WHOLE fields as `ScrollView` can hold only one DIRECT CHILD.
4. **Most important point:** Add too many address field as you can see SCROLL at runtime. Just copy-paste address field and change the ids field of them.

Below is screen shot, which I have got as Outcome. And See this [CodeLink](http://hastebin.com/patetiripa.xml).

[image: OutCom]

Hope this will help.

Comment: Actually it works but y there is too many address field here i want only one in my layout ..When i changed the address field to one from multiple again its not scrolling

Comment: It is just for testing purpose of scrolling functionality of `<ScrollView>`. Have you checked out **CodeLink** provided in my answer? Just check it out!@Preethi Rajan

Comment: Yea i checked ur code and its working very fine when i ve more Address field when i min to one d prob still exist

Comment: What is the problem? Is it not **SCROLLING**?@PreethiRajan

Comment: yea its not scrolling

Comment: Actually `<ScrollView>` will do scrolling when It's **CHILD** has many **VIEWS** such that they exceeds the **SCREEN HEIGHT** limit. Although, If you want to do **SCROLLING** you have to set `layout_height` of `ScrollView` to some specific value.

For example set it to `150dp`.

Now, It will do scrolling. Hope this will help you.@PreethiRajan

Comment: its working when i give nos but when i change the no to match parent or fill parent its not ..

Comment: I suggest you to **READ** documentation of `<ScrollView>`. It might help you. If I solve your **PROBLEM** please do **ACCEPT** my answer.@PreethiRajan

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView hold only one view as Childview try this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.agna.hrm_sainmarks.Address">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/emergencytoolbar"
        layout="@layout/emergency_toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/name"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Ajith Kumar"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/relationship"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primrelationship"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Brother"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/phone"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primphone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="9998885231"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/taddress"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primaddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="78,Muthu nagar 3rd Street,Coimbatore-44"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The data below is not displaying toolbar is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

> As `Scroll View` can hold only one direct child.You need to define it above Your `Main Linear Layout`. Also use `Scroll Bars Property` in `Scroll View`.

**EDIT :**

> Move your `Tool Bar` Layout above `Scroll View`.

**Try this code.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.agna.hrm_sainmarks.Address">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/emergencytoolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emergencytoolbar"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"

            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Ajith Kumar"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primrelationship"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Brother"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="phone"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primphone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="9998885231"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primaddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="78,Muthu nagar 3rd Street,Coimbatore-44"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its still the same whole layout is scrolling i want only data below toolbar to scroll

Comment: @PreethiRajan Check i have updated xml code again. it will work for you.i have checked your layout and tested. Replace this  XML code.

Comment: @PreethiRajan In my previous update have you changed your tool bar layout name and i have added `layout_below` in scroll view. have you replace code ? i think it is working here. make sure changes i have done that applied.

Comment: Totally I ve 2 tool bar in my proj.  First it displays the profile image followed by my main tool bar and then the second one....as above occupies most of the space i want the data below second tool bar to scroll

Comment: Where is your second `tool bar` ? i don't be able to see that even in your OP `XML` code. My previous change will scroll your data below emergancy tool bar you hve.

Comment: i added that toolbar using custom adapter

Comment: Custom adapter toolbar means as i understood is your emergancy tool bar right ?

Comment: no it contains address,emergency detail etc and in emergency detail i ve two buttons emergency primary and secondary information and the layout i posted is for emergency primary same prob i ve for secondary too

Comment: can i see xml code for this `layout="@layout/emergency_toolbar" ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I tried to add data to it and then scrolled. The views below toolbar are being scrolled as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="in.net.codestar.ratingbar.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/emergencytoolbar"
        layout="@layout/emergency_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/name"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Ajith Kumar"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/relationship"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primrelationship"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Brother"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/phone"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primphone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="9998885231"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/taddress"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/primaddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="78,Muthu nagar 3rd Street,Coimbatore-4478,Muthu nagar 3rd Street,Coimbatore-44"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Hrmbg" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

emergency_toobar.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pemergency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="@color/Hrmbg"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="@string/pemergency"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/semergency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="@color/Hrmbg"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="@string/semergency"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey its Scrolling but the complete data is not displaying thru scroll and i want to add extra lines to the data, only then its scrolling till end

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines solved my problem:

```
android:lines="4"
android:maxLines="4"
```

now it's working.

Comment: Please dont mind but IMHO, It's a **PATCH.** The proper way is **RUN-OVER** in other answers. Take a look at **MY ANSWER** too.@Preethi Rajan

Comment: Can u pls post ur answer

Comment: Posted my answer.@Preethi Rajan

Comment: It's not a **PROPER** way to solve this issue. The other answers have better **ELIGIBILITY** as **ACCEPTED** answers.@Preethi Rajan